# how to come back to different view after opening the safari through another view in iphone application?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using tabbar based application. I have 9 tabbar items. I'm calling the safari in my 6th tabbar item. When i close the safari and open the app again i want my app to open the 2nd tab in the application. Can any one help me out in this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try programmatically set tab bar selected index to 2  applicationDidBecomeActive/applicationDidFinishLaunching(if your app does not run in background). You can search on google and you will easily find the answer.

Comment: I tried selected index. My 6th tabbar item is under more option. When i use selected index, it show me the correct item, but when i again click the more option it directly takes me to the safari which is called from the 6th tabbar item.

Comment: it seems your app is running in background. You need quit your app when user presses home button. Try setting a key in info.plist named application does not run in background and set flag to true. Search on google or stackoverflow you will find the key.